# Telegram Webhook error:14095044:SSL routines:ssl3_read_n:internal error

Tags: ssl-certificate, telegram, telegram-webhook

This error seems to be a rare one since google doesn't cough up anything. (There do exist questions and answers for different Telegram Webhook error messages.)

So this is mine:

```
{"ok":true,"result":{"url":"https://blablabla.com:8443/mytgmhook",
"has_custom_certificate":false,
"pending_update_count":22,
"last_error_date":1535648677,
"last_error_message":"SSL error {
error:14095044:SSL routines:ssl3_read_n:internal error
}","max_connections":40}}
```

For context:

I am running a newly set up Amazon Linux 2 on EC2.

I have created SSL certificates using LetsEncrypt and Amazon's instructions. I have verified the setup on ssllabs.com and it's all green.

I have opened the ports 443 and 8443 and tested them, they work, traffic gets through.

The site is accessible via https on both domain.com and www.domain.com

This error message is preventing me from getting and parsing the bot inputs. They never arrive to my server. Note that it didn't stop working -- it never worked.

Any ideas please?

EDIT:

I have discovered that if I keep refreshing the getWebhookInfo, the above error is sometimes replaced with this one:

```
"last_error_message":"SSL error {
error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
}","max_connections":40}}
```

I have launched a brand new EC2 instance, with Ubuntu this time, and I get the same error.

I am still at a loss as how to solve this.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Did you solve it? And how?
I'm trying to use a bot hosted on Heroku. I've tried both not providing a certificate file in the "setWebhook" request and providing the file found at `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` in the Heroku dyno. The result is the same.

Comment: Also having this problem, if solved it, please share with us

Answer (score 0):

1 - use `openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -nodes -keyout YOURPRIVATE.key -x509 -days 365 -out YOURPUBLIC.pem -subj "/C=US/ST=New York/L=Brooklyn/O=Example Brooklyn Company/CN=YOURDOMAIN.EXAMPLE"`
to create your certificate;

2 - remember to put the IP address of your server in YOURDOMAIN.EXAMPLE

Comment: what are the next steps ? I tried posting the ssl certificate to webhooks of telegram but it didn't work. Getting connection refused error on telegram.

Comment: @Tanveer Have you fixed that issue? Can you share your solution?